# Argument Exception unhandled visual basic and SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Hi I have made a Visual Basic project in it I read from a database (The table is called Customers) but when I output the variable I saved it to it comes up with system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader  instead of the value of that column.
this is the Vb;

```
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT user FROM Customers", connection)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Dim output As String = Convert.ToString(reader)
    MsgBox(output)
```

The SQL is;

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL , 
    [user] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 34313431, 
    [password] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 343134, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I don't know what database I,m using. @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a reserved word in [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) (and other databases).  This may be the cause of your problem.

Try:

```
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT [user] FROM Customers", connection)
```

Comment: it still returns system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader instead of the value of the column. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: This is not the actual problem, problem relies on `Dim output As String = Convert.ToString(reader)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have multple rows in column `user` in `Customers` Table

```
 Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT user FROM Customers", Connection)
 Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
 Dim output As String 
 If reader.HasRows Then /* Check whether reader has any rows */
    While reader.Read /* Read is a must so that we can get data from reader*/
     /*'Your code,For example below given will loop through each row*/
      output = output & " " & reader.Item("user")
    End While
 End If
```

`Dim output As String = Convert.ToString(reader)` - Is wrong

Read these articles for more info : - [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)  and [How to ADO.NET SqlDataReader](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-sqldatareader.htm)